# Controlling alpha value on 3D scatter plot using Python and matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm plotting a 3D scatter plot using the function scatter and mplot3d. I'm choosing a single color for all points in the plot, but when drawn by matplotlib the transparency of the points is set relative to the distance from the camera. Is there any way to disable this feature?

I've tried setting the alpha kwarg to None/1 and also set vmin/vmax to 1 (in an attempt to force the color scaling to be a solid single color) with no luck. I didn't see any other likely options related to this setting in the scatter documentation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**For Matplotlib 1.4+, the answer provided below by @fraxel is the best solution: call `ax.scatter` with the argument `depthshade=False`.**

There is no arguments that can control this. Here is some hack method.

Disable `set_edgecolors` and `set_facecolors` method, so that mplot3d can't update the alpha part of the colors:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

x = np.random.sample(20)
y = np.random.sample(20)
z = np.random.sample(20)
s = ax.scatter(x, y, z, c="r")
s.set_edgecolors = s.set_facecolors = lambda *args:None

ax.legend()
ax.set_xlim3d(0, 1)
ax.set_ylim3d(0, 1)
ax.set_zlim3d(0, 1)

plt.show()
```

[image]

If you want call `set_edgecolors` and `set_facecolors` methods later, you can backup these two methods before disable them:

```
s._set_facecolors, s._set_edgecolors = s.set_facecolors, s.set_edgecolors
```

Comment: If ever there was a programming solution that could be called "cheeky" .. :)

Answer (score 13):

```
ax.scatter(x, y, z, depthshade=0)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer (for recent matplotlib versions)

Comment: unfortunately does not work with colormaps :/ something like this:  `cmap = "inferno";
surf = ax.scatter(xx, yy, zz, marker='o', c = zz, cmap = cmap, depthshade = False);
fig.colorbar(surf, aspect=40)`

Comment: instead this works : `ax.scatter(xval, yval, zval, c=cval, alpha = 1, cmap=plt.cm.gray)` with alpha set to 1

Answer (score 6):

If you only want to disable the alpha adjustment, you can overwrite the zalpha function. This will allow you to update the colors in the case of an interactive plot and still remove the depth fog.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()

art3d.zalpha = lambda *args:args[0]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

x = np.random.sample(20)
y = np.random.sample(20)
z = np.random.sample(20)
s = ax.scatter(x, y, z, c="r")

ax.legend()
ax.set_xlim3d(0, 1)
ax.set_ylim3d(0, 1)
ax.set_zlim3d(0, 1)

plt.show()
```