# matplotlib 3D scatter plot alpha varies when viewing different angles

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

When creating 3D scatter plots with matplotlib I noticed that when the alpha (transparency) of the points is varied it will draw them differently depending on how you rotate the view. The example images below are the same plot rotated slightly, which causes the alpha values to mysteriously reverse. Is anyone familiar with this behavior and how to address it? It looks like the 'zorder' (draw order) is a single value for the entire scatter plot call.

[image][image]

Simplified example code to recreate:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection="3d")

X = [i for i in range(10)]
Y = [i for i in range(10)]
Z = [i for i in range(10)]
S = [(i+1)*400 for i in range(10)]
A = [i/10 for i in range(10)]

ax.scatter(xs=X, ys=Y, zs=Z, s=S, alpha=A)

plt.show()
```

- Python 3.9.5
- matplotlib 3.5.1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Controlling alpha value on 3D scatter plot using Python and matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15533246/controlling-alpha-value-on-3d-scatter-plot-using-python-and-matplotlib)

Comment: No, unfortunately the depthshade and art3d.zalpha (deprecated) solutions do not make a difference.

Comment: After some testing I found that both alpha and depthshade independently cause the issue if either, or both are enabled.

Answer (score 2):

I also posted this on the [matplotlib github](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/22861) to see what the developers think.

It appears to be a bug with a very low priority, per their latest response: "*We have limited core developer resources and mpl_toolkits/mplot3d is only a secondary priority for the core team. Likely this needs someone in the community to pick up and provide a fix.*"

I will try to do so, but am posting this for visibility in the meantime so that other people with more experience are made aware.

Answer (score 1):

One possible workaround is to add each point with a `for` loop, for example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection="3d")

X = [i for i in range(10)]
Y = [i for i in range(10)]
Z = [i for i in range(10)]
S = [(i+1)*400 for i in range(10)]
A = [i/10 for i in range(10)]

for x, y, z, s, a in zip(X, Y, Z, S, A):
    ax.scatter(xs=x, ys=y, zs=z, s=s, alpha=a, color="tab:blue")

plt.show()
```

Comment: Yes, this does address the strange alpha behavior, but I would prefer not to use a for loop if possible. The plot is much much slower using this method with large numbers of datapoints.